# Can't debug in QT creator with cmake project

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I created a new Plain C++ Project with CMake Build.
When I set a breakpoint and press the Debug Button I get this message:

```
This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.
Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.

Section .debug_info: Not found.
Section .debug_abbrev: Not found.
Section .debug_line: Not found.
Section .debug_str: Not found.
Section .debug_loc: Not found.
Section .debug_range: Not found.
Section .gdb_index: Not found.
Section .note.gnu.build-id: Found.
Section .gnu.hash: Found.
Section .gnu_debuglink: Not found.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add this *CMake argument* to your *Build Settings*:

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this?

Comment: added a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, even with this setting it still is release type

Comment: In QtCreator 3.5, the CMake arguments are available only when rebuilding CMake generated makefiles - it is a separate popup window and not the form under Build Settings.